# Label distinct combinations across multiple columns in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I want to create a new column that labels each unique combination of values across `x`, `y`, `z` columns. My current work-around to achieve that is this:

```
> library(tidyverse) 
> 
> set.seed(100)
> df = tibble(x = sample.int(5, 50, replace = T), y = sample.int(5, 50, replace = T), z = sample.int(5, 50, replace = T))
> df
# A tibble: 50 x 3
       x     y     z
   <int> <int> <int>
 1     2     4     4
 2     3     4     4
 3     1     3     5
 4     2     1     4
 5     4     2     5
 6     4     5     2
 7     2     3     4
 8     3     5     4
 9     2     4     1
10     5     5     2
# … with 40 more rows
> 
> df2 = df %>% distinct(x,y,z) %>% rowid_to_column("unique_id") %>% left_join(df)
Joining, by = c("x", "y", "z")
> df2
# A tibble: 50 x 4
   unique_id     x     y     z
       <int> <int> <int> <int>
 1         1     2     4     4
 2         2     3     4     4
 3         3     1     3     5
 4         4     2     1     4
 5         4     2     1     4
 6         5     4     2     5
 7         5     4     2     5
 8         6     4     5     2
 9         6     4     5     2
10         7     2     3     4
# … with 40 more rows
```

What is a better/more efficient way to do this on a fairly large dataset? I'd like to stay within `tidyverse` but also open to other suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `rleidv` from `data.table`

```
df$unique_id <- data.table::rleidv(df)
```

In `dplyr`, we can use `group_indices` function for this purpose which generates a unique id for each group of values.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(unique_id = group_indices(., x, y, z))
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `devel` version of `dplyr`, we can use `cur_group_id`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
     group_by_all() %>% 
     mutate(unique_id = cur_group_id())
```

Or using `.GRP` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, unique_id := .GRP, names(df)]
```